# Why am I facing problem with gh pages deploy?

Tags: deployment, create-react-app, github-pages

I deployed my create-react-app to gh pages and added basic routing but I have problem everytime i run deploy. The problem is that in gh branch -> index.html my link for js file is '/blabla/static/...' but it was suppossed to be './static...' to work and I have to fix it manually on my github everytime i run deploy. Is there any possible way to automate it ?

"homepage": "https://github.com/FreedomFighterr.github.io"

Homepage is set like this because if i have another /myproject then my app wouldn't load, it only works like this. Is it maybe problem with homepage ?